# iMac not turning on after power cut mid update

Tags: imac

I was updating my iMac 2019 27in (less than 4 months old) and we had a power cut.

I now cannot turn my iMac on.

It boots up, I can hear the fan. But nothing appears on the screen. No apple logo.

I have tried booting in safe mode but it doesn't work and I've tried resetting SMC.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: If the power failed during a firmware update this may require replacing the system board. Most PCs warn against removing the power during firmware upgrades. The very few times this has happened to me (Dell PCs) it required a system board replacment. It was fixed under warranty as all I told Dell was that the system would (barely) power on and no further. Unfortunately Apple doesn't even tell you that firmware is being updated... sigh.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I had to resort to taking it in to Apple and they are replacing the logic board!

Answer (score 2):

You covered Apple’s triage steps nicely and I think you hit them all.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267

Unless you can see something on an external monitor or the internal monitor booting with an option key held or internet recovery and see signs of life on screen, your next step is a repair shop to determine which component inside has failed.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

My hope is you can boot to internet recovery and choose to reinstall the OS. Since you were mid update, it likely left your data alone and the system totally needing a reinstall. If you weren’t updating, the hardware failure is more likely, but can’t be ruled out based on the symptoms.

You can also bring a bootable USB to that Mac and test operation / hardware without needing service help.